# access to an object in jquery ajax with mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I send some data to action with jquery ajax and I want to show the returned data in table. In this work, I have an action method that return an object in Json format, like this:

```
public JsonResult CountryList(.....)
{
    CountryTypeViewModel obj = new CountryTypeViewModel();
    .
    .
    return Json(obj);
}
```

and my `CountryTypeViewModel` like this:

```
public class CountryTypeViewModel
{
    public List<CountryViewModel> CountryList { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage;
    public int pageSize;
    public double TotalPages;
    public int sortBy;
    public bool isAsc;
    public string Search;
    public int isLastRecord;
    public int Count;
}

public class CountryViewModel
{
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
}
```

in my .cshtml I have this:
the important part of this code that I had problem with, is `success: function (data)`.

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(function () {
        $('#pageSize').change(function () {
            var pagesize = $("#pageSize :selected").val();
            if (pagesize != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '@Url.Action("CountryList", "GridView")',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ "page": @Model.CurrentPage, "sortBy": @Model.sortBy,
                        "isAsc": @Model.isAsc.ToString().ToLower(),
                        "TotalCount": @Model.TotalPages, "pageSize": pagesize}),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var items = "";
                        $.each(data, function (i, cuntr) {
                            items += '<tr><td>'+ cuntr.CountryList.CountryID +'</td><td>'+ cuntr.CountryList.Name +'</td><td>'+ cuntr.CountryList.Region +'</td></tr>';
                        });
                        // Fill Table
                        $('#countryData').html(items);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + ' Type :' + result.statusText);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

everything work fine, the data sent to action and the json response (list of country with other property) came to browser. **But**, it can't show the received data in table!
the JSON responce that come is:

```
{"CurrentPage":1,"pageSize":25,"TotalPages":36,"sortBy":1,"isAsc":true,"Search":null,"isLastRecord":0
,"Count":0,"CountryList":[{"CountryID":1,"Name":"Afghanistan","Region":"Central"},{"CountryID":2,"Name"
:"Albania","Region":"Europe"},{"CountryID":3,"Name":"Andorra","Region":"Europe"},{"CountryID":4,"Name"
:"Algeria","Region":"Africa"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not iterating on the right object. You need to iterate on the CountryList. Try the following in your success:

```
 success: function (data) {
                    var items = "<table>";
                    $.each(data.CountryList, function (i, cuntr) {
                        items += '<tr><td>'+ cuntr.CountryID +'</td><td>'+ cuntr.Name +'</td><td>'+ cuntr.Region +'</td></tr>';
                    });
items+='</table>'
                    // Fill Table
                    $('#countryData').html(items);
                },
```

Comment: and If I want to access other element, like "pageSize" or "TotalPages" in JSON response, what can I do?

Comment: you can do data.pageSize and data.TotalPages. The thing is those properties are under the data object returned. So you directly access them like that.